# Update from tomcat 7.0.63 to 7.0.82 and now oracle Connection does not work

Tags: oracle, apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, datasource

I had been running an application on apache tomcat 7.0.63 on Linux, and it uses a datasource setup in the server.xml GlobalNamingResources section.  Then in the context.xml we have a ResourceLink setup that references it.  These are referenced in the application's WEB-INF/web.xml file.  When running on 7.0.63, it works great, however when running it on the 7.0.82 binaries I get an error. I have been digging into this for a while now, anyone have any helpful hints as to what to look at next?

Here is what I see:

First, the initial error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Foobar] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /foobar/foobar.jsp at line 46
```

RootCause from same log:

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at foo.bar.dal.OracleDatabaseConnector.open(OracleDatabaseConnector.java:31)
        at foo.bar.dal.DataAccess.openConnection(DataAccess.java:81)
        at foo.bar.referralForm.ReferralFormPageBean.lookupUserFromLdap(ReferralFormPageBean.java:412)
        at foo.bar.referralForm.ReferralFormPageBean.initIfLoaded(ReferralFormPageBean.java:58)
        at foo.bar.referralForm.ReferralFormPageBean.setResponse(ReferralFormPageBean.java:53)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.handleSetPropertyExpression(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:562)
        at org.apache.jsp.ReferralForm.InvestigativeReferralForm_jsp._jspService(InvestigativeReferralForm_jsp.java:166)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: At a guess `foo.bar.dal.OracleDatabaseConnector.open` is your code.  What is on line 31 in the file `OracleDatabaseConnector.java`?

Comment: The code is just looking up the jdbc context, that I can see when connecting over JMX, but for some reason it's giving him a NullPointer.